# (Python) Get HTML from website opened in user's browser

Tags: python, html, google-chrome, browser

Instead of a Selenium session, I'd like to fetch data from the regular Chrome session because the data is already present there and recreating the same scenario in selenium takes too long for it to be handy.
Is there any way of seeing HTML of a currently opened tab?

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using `urllib.request` for this:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen

link = "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68120200/python-get-html-       from-website-opened-in-users-browser"
openedpage = urlopen(link)
content = openedpage.read()
code = bytes.decode("utf-8")
print(code)
```

This would for example give out the code for the page of this question. Hope this is what you wanted to achieve. In case you wanted to extract actual data and not code, you can do that with the same library:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen

link = "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68120200/python-get-html-from-website-opened-in-users-browser"
openedpage = urlopen(link)
content = openedpage.read()
code = content.decode("utf-8")
title = code.find("<title>")
title_start = title + len("<title>")
title_end = code.find("</title>")
full_title = code[title_start:title_end]
print(full_title)
```

Basically what you want to do to get any part of the code is to collect the start and end-index of the tag, end then combine them together like in the example.

Comment: I need an actual browser to open it because of security meassures, and Selenium/Playwright take too long for it to be handy.